# Sometimes, the cmd gets stuck when executed from C#

Tags: c#, command-line

The code below is the method I'm using to execute CMD commands. On the production server, it sometimes gets stuck for no apparent reason, even though I have already applied a timeout method. Despite this, it still occasionally gets stuck.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace SharedLibraries.Helpers
{

    public class CommandExecutor
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger;
        private const int DefaultTimeoutMilliseconds = 10000;
        public CommandExecutor(Logger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public bool ExecuteCommand(string command, out string result, int timeoutMilliseconds = DefaultTimeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            Process? process = new()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = $"/c {command}",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                }
            };

            StringBuilder? output = new();
            StringBuilder? error = new();

            try
            {
                _logger.Log(message: $"Executing command: '{command}'", LogLevel.INFO);
                process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) => { output.AppendLine(args.Data); };
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) => { error.AppendLine(args.Data); };

                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                if (!process.WaitForExit(milliseconds: timeoutMilliseconds))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    result = "Command execution timed out.";
                    _logger.Log(message: $"Command timeout. Command: '{command}', Timeout: {timeoutMilliseconds}ms", LogLevel.ERROR);
                    return false;
                }

                process.WaitForExit();

                string errorOutput = error.ToString().Trim();
                if (process.ExitCode != 0 || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value: errorOutput))
                {
                    result = $"Command execution failed with exit code {process.ExitCode}:\n{errorOutput}";
                    _logger.Log(message: $"Command execution failed. Command: '{command}', Exit Code: {process.ExitCode}, Error: {errorOutput}", LogLevel.ERROR);
                    return false;
                }

                result = output.ToString().Trim();
                _logger.Log(message: $"Command executed successfully. Command: '{command}', Result:\n{result}", LogLevel.INFO);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = $"Error executing command: {ex.Message}";
                _logger.Log(message: $"Exception during command execution. Command: '{command}', Exception: {ex}", LogLevel.ERROR);
                return false;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on and suggest a method to improve the timeout mechanism? I'm looking for a solution that will allow the system to return 'false' when it becomes stuck.

Comment: From my experience Process class is awful proxy. It can definitely get stuck ocasionaly, not be initialized on Start or just be plain dead or not offloading after service reboot. In the end nothing worked and I ended up doing something like watcher-exe which spawns along target process and run healthcheck on both parent and child. https://github.com/eocron/Sharding/blob/master/Eocron.Sharding/Processing/IShardProcessJob.cs It can be pretty simple in your case, but it's hard to understand what's exactly happening.

Comment: For example, it can stuck waiting input from user (credentials, etc). Then you get a zombie.

Comment: IMHO don't use the `.BeginXXXReadLine` methods and create a thread / task to read from `.StandardOutput` & `.StandardError`, completely independently from waiting for the process to exit. Otherwise you risk the child process blocking while trying to write output, because the OS buffer is full since you haven't read it yet.

Comment: Why set up to read the io asynchronously but then synchronously wait for exit? If something goes wrong your code is blocked and has essentially lost any ability to control the situation.. Use the Exited event instead?

Comment: Also, mostly the list of commands you're running can probably be done by c#, which would be more controlled than shelling out